# what exceptions can occur with mysql statements?

Tags: mysql, exception

I'm developing a website in php and codeignitor with three collegues, we're using mysql database.

I know that insert can throw an exception due to constraint violation, connect the server can make exception too if the server is busy.

Now what are other exceptions that might occur ? I tried looking in the web and I'm surprised I didn't find what I want, My webapp is a link-sharing website with tags, votes, flags,comments, and search(by title and tags, no advanced search yet) .

### PS

Obviously we're not going to handle errors(like bad sector) so exceptions is what we want here.

Answer (score -1):

Other common errors are:

- The various php-generated catchable fatal errors. See here. http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php
- php's out of memory error, which you cannot catch.
- php's maximum execution time error, also which you cannot catch.
- all sorts of MySQL errors.

Many web application software developers create a last-chance error handler. It logs the error message and any available stack trace to a log file and presents a "sorry, that didn't work" page to the user.

As you might guess, it's best not to use MySQL to log errors, because if it's MySQL failing, it won't work.

This is a community wiki page. That means anybody can edit it.

Comment: hmmmm maybe you check my PS :)